# How I can merge 2 databases into a single one?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

In a single server I have 2 Databases:

- `db1` with schema public
- `bd2` with schema public as well.

What I want it to merge them into a single Database `final_db` where:

- schema `db1.public` will be `final_db.public`
- schema `db2.public` will be `final_db.db2`

Both databases are in a single postgresql 11 server. At the same time both read and write operations do exist in `db1` and `db2` databases. Therefore I would love on how I can realtime tranfer:

- Existing data
- Incomming data

From both `db1` and `db2` databases into `final_db` wuithtout data loss. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to stop the application while you move the data.

- dump and restore `db2` into `final_db`
- rename schema `public` to `db2`
- dump and restore `db1` into `final_db`

The second operation could cause some errors, for example if the same extension was installed in both databases. All these errors should be safe to ignore.

Care has to be taken if the `db2` application is supposed to continue working: if the application does not set `search_path` and does not refer to tables by schema name, perhaps you can get away with changing `search_path` for the application user of that application with `ALTER ROLE`.

I see no benefit in merging the two databases like that. Two applications should use two databases.

Comment: After dump and merging the databases, existing apps will continue to write into `db1` and `db2` databases whilst I merge them alltogether. Until I switch the database settings Into each app I may have some data loss. Is there a way to move any leftover data whilst I switch the database settings?

Comment: No, you will have to stop the applications.

Comment: Is there a way to have some sort of "transdlation proxy" and redirect connections into translation proxy? Tjhe proxy will hafta sync the data  till I transfer.

Comment: God knows what tools are out there, but asking for tools is off-topic. Just leave the databases the way they are now.

Comment: I agree with @LaurenzAlbe, I see no need to separate the databases. This even makes restore operations easier if you want to restore only one app/database. To add though, you might be able to get away with it if you rename one schema and then implement logical replication from both databases to the new database, wait for all tables to catch up and then switch the apps to the new database. However, I recommend rigorous testing before attempting something like that.